# Como cambiar validación numérica a validación por cadena

Tags: javascript

Actualmente cuento con una validación en donde deshabilito los botones dependiendo dependiendo del valor numérico de la siguiente manera:

```
disabled = [0,2,3,5]

/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format(d) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    $tipoproveedor = $("#txttipoproveedor").val();
    console.log(d);
      let tabla = `<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 40px 5px;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Fecha de recepción
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Recepción
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Estatus
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>`;
                                                        
                            d.Factura.forEach(f => {                            
                                tabla += `<tr>                                                         
                                <td>${f.FechaFactura}</td>
                                <td>${f.Factura}</td>       
                                <td>${f.Estatus}</td>                                                                                           
                                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalCargaFactura" onclick="CargarFactura('${f.OrdenCompra}' )"`;
                 
                                if($tipoproveedor != '0'){
                                    if (disabled.indexOf(f.Estatus) > -1) {
                                        tabla += ` disabled `;
                                    }
                                }    
                                  tabla += `>Cargar Documentos</button></td>                               
                                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="MostrarDetalleFactura('${f.Factura}')">Ver Detalle</button></td>
                                </tr>`;
                            });
                       tabla += '</tbody></table>';
                       return tabla;    
}
```

En donde deshabilito el botón en los valores `0,2,3,5`, ahora estos valores cambiaran a cadenas dándole la siguiente asignación a los valores numéricos así:

```
0 = 'Ninguno'
2 = 'Aceptado'
3 = 'Enviado'
5 = 'Entregado'
```

Lo que requiero ahora es validar ya no con los números si no con la cadena de caracteres, espero que alguien me pueda dar un poco de orientación con esta validación.

**Actualización 1:**

En base a la respuesta he realizado el siguiente código cambiando mi array de valores por cadenas de la siguiente manera:

```
disabled = ['Ninguno','Aceptado','Enviado','Entregado']

/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format(d) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    $tipoproveedor = $("#txttipoproveedor").val();
    console.log(d);
      let tabla = `<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 40px 5px;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Fecha de recepción
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Recepción
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Estatus
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>`;

                            d.Factura.forEach(f => {                            
                                tabla += `<tr>                                                         
                                <td>${f.FechaFactura}</td>
                                <td>${f.Factura}</td>       
                                <td>${f.Estatus}</td>                                                                                           
                                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalCargaFactura" onclick="CargarFactura('${f.OrdenCompra}' )"`;

                                if($tipoproveedor != '0'){
                                    if (disabled.indexOf(f.Estatus) > -1) {
                                        tabla += ` disabled `;
                                    }
                                }    
                                  tabla += `>Cargar Documentos</button></td>                               
                                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="MostrarDetalleFactura('${f.Factura}')">Ver Detalle</button></td>
                                </tr>`;
                            });
                       tabla += '</tbody></table>';
                       return tabla;    
}
```

Intentándolo de esta manera he obtenido el siguiente error:

```
Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
```

A lo poco que entiendo yo es que la validación ya no detecta los valores numéricos que existían en el arreglo `disabled` y por esta razón marca el error y no se carga los datos en la tabla.

Explicara un poco mas a detalle, actualmente tengo en la tabla la columna `Estatus` donde se muestran los valores `0,2,3,5` y se realiza la deshabilitación o habilitación de los botones dependiendo de su valor. En este caso me he visto obligado a cambiar estos mismos valores por cadenas y para no complicarme mucho la vida he decidido hacer este cambio desde la consulta con la cual muestro los datos en la tabla con su simple `case` así:

```
CASE ESTATUS
                WHEN 0 THEN 'Ninguno'
                WHEN 1 THEN 'Recibido'
                WHEN 2 THEN 'Aceptado'
                WHEN 3 THEN 'Enviado'
                WHEN 4 THEN 'Procesado'
                WHEN 5 THEN 'Entregado'
                ELSE 'Otro'
            END as 'Estatus'
```

Comment: Tengo una duda sobre donde cambiaras los valores numéricos por las cadenas. Me explico: ¿disabled ahora será un array con los nuevos valores ('Ninguno'...)? y en el objeto factura (d.Factura) el campo Estatus ¿qué valores tendrá números o cadenas?.

Comment: Estos valores dentro del objeto `factura` ahora tendrán cadenas debido a que en la consulta desde base de datos realizar un `case when then` para remplazar los valores numéricos por letras

Comment: Vale, entonces ¿porqué no conviertes también disabled en un array con esos valores? Si lo haces no tienes que cambiar nada más. Fíjate que el comprobar el boton debe estar deshabilitado busca f.Estatus ('Ninguno'. 'Enviado', etc) dentro del array  disabled que ahora contendrían esas cadenas. La búsqueda es igual que con los números.

Comment: @Juan pero la validación `if (disabled.indexOf(f.Estatus) > -1) { tabla += ` disabled `; }`  tendría que cambiar? lo digo porque aquí lo realiza con números

Comment: Si cambias el array disabled y pones las cadenas en lugar de números la validación no tiene que cambiar. Al hacer esto estás buscando las cadenas de Estatus en una lista de cadenas (disbled) la validación busca la cadena Estatus en la lista de cadenas disabled. Ahora mismo como lo tienes (todo números) busca el número de Estatsu en la lista de numeros disabled. La función de buscar no cambia.

Comment: No se que otro uso tiene el array disabled en relación al error JSON (supongo que se usará en una llamada AJAX),. ¿Has seguido los pasos que te indican en  http://datatables.net/tn/1 para diagnosticar el origen del error?

Comment: ¿Si dejas disabled con números sigue saliendo el error?

Comment: @Juan El array `disabled `con los números no sale error, se debe a que la validación esta hecha para validar con los números, ahora lo que requiero es que en vez de validar con los números lo valide con un array de cadenas.

Comment: Entonces si no se puede tocar disabled solo queda retocar el código de validación, y volver a comparar número de disabled con el número que corresponde al estado.  Te edito la respuesta es más cómodo que el comentario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mira lo que yo he hecho a partir de tu pregunta

```js
disabled = [0,2,3,5];
lista ={Factura:[
{FechaFactura:"2/2/21", Factura:1, Estatus: "Ninguno"},
{FechaFactura:"2/3/21", Factura:5, Estatus: "Entregado"},
{FechaFactura:"2/5/21", Factura:12, Estatus:"Aceptado"},
{FechaFactura:"2/6/21", Factura:20, Estatus:"Otro"}
]}
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format(d) {
// `d` is the original data object for the row
$tipoproveedor = $("#txttipoproveedor").val();
console.log(d);
let tabla = `<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 40px 5px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Fecha de recepción
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Recepción
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Estatus
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>`;

                    d.Factura.forEach(f => {                            
                        tabla += `<tr>                                                         
                        <td>${f.FechaFactura}</td>
                        <td>${f.Factura}</td>       
                        <td>${f.Estatus}</td>                                                                                           
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalCargaFactura" onclick="CargarFactura('${f.OrdenCompra}' )"`;
//Cambio para no tocar disabled
var estados=['Ninguno', 'Recibido','Aceptado','Enviado','Procesado', 'Entregado', 'Otro'];
if($tipoproveedor != '0'){
//Calcula el número del estado para comparar con disabled.
    let numEstado = estados.indexOf(f.Estatus);  
    if (disabled.indexOf(numEstado) > -1) {
        tabla += ` disabled `;
    }
}    
  tabla += `>Cargar Documentos</button></td>                               
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="MostrarDetalleFactura('${f.Factura}')">Ver Detalle</button></td>
</tr>`;
  });
 tabla += '</tbody></table>';
 return tabla;    
}
document.write(format(lista));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="txttipoproveedor">2</div>
```

Yo he puesto este código en una página con un bloque 2 para evitar el error de variable no encontrada.
La variable lista la he deducido por la estructura del código que pones en la pregunta.
Ejecuta y verás que los botones salen deshabilitados menos en el que he puesto como Estatus 'Otro' (para comprobar) y observa que la validación es tal como tu la tienes en tu pregunta.
Ah, y he añadido al final del `document.write()` para que se vea el resultado.
Espero que responda a la cuestión.

**EDITADO**

`Disabled` vuelve a ser un array de números

He cambiado parte del código para no tocar `disabled`

```
var estados=['Ninguno',   
'Recibido',  
'Aceptado',  
'Enviado',  
'Procesado',   
'Entregado',   
'Otro'];
if($tipoproveedor != '0'){  
    let numEstado = estados.indexOf(f.Estatus);  
    if (disabled.indexOf(numEstado) > -1) {  
        tabla += ` disabled `;  
    }
```

Como no se puede tocar `disabled` y `f.Estatus` ahora es una cadena, pues creo un array con los posibles estados en su orden (el del CASE) en forma de cadena y miro que número le corresponde al estado actual. Ahora valida  comprobando con `disabled`.

Comment: He intentado lo de tu respuesta pero ahora me marca un error el cual agregue en una actualización a la pregunta, quiero pensar que el error sucede porque la validación ya no cuento con datos numéricos, es posible que se pueda revisar esta validación ?

Comment: Me perdí. Entendí que el Estatus venía de una base de datos donde se almacenaba como cadena. Entonces ¿al final es sólo cuestión de mostrar un número o una palabra en la columna de estado? Y ni idea que había un JSON de por medio ¿hay un AJAX en otra parte?

Comment: En la base de datos con el `CASE` que agregue ahora se remplazaran esos valores numéricos por cadenas, y lo que requiero mostrar en mi tabla ahora son esas mismas cadenas pero de mi cuenta que mi validación para deshabilitar los botones solo tiene en cuenta los valores numéricos, lo que requiero ahora es que en vez de validar contra los valores numéricos ahora lo haga con las cadenas.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que en `f.Estatus` en lugar de un código númerico ahora viene una cadena que  puede ser una de las siguientes:'Ninguno', 'Recibido', 'Aceptado', 'Enviado', 'Procesado', 'Entregado' u 'Otros'. Si es  así puedes validar f.Estatus de la siguiente forma:

```
// Declaramos un diccionario. El valor de cada campo es arbitrario. 
var disabled = {Ninguno: 0, Recibido: 1,Aceptado: 2, Enviado:3, Procesado:4, Entregado:5}

// En la  validación

    if($tipoproveedor != '0'){

       if (disabled[f.Estatus]) {

          // f.Estatus está en la tabla
              tabla += ` disabled `;

          }
     }
```